# OC command to view the tag information

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I would like to know the tag applied to all the images in a namespace. Is there any **oc** command to view tags in a namespace?

Before posting this question, i googled. However i didn't find any. So I am posting this question here.

Comment: You can view details of all image streams in a project by running ``oc describe is``. This will list tags for each image stream along with lots of other information. Add an extra argument of a specific image stream to be selective.

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton, Thank you for prompt response. let me put my requirement, "retrieve all images with  <b>"release" tag <\b> in a namespace." I see <i>oc get is -n <namespace> </i> providing information. But i was wondering is there any easy way to get like application name and all the tag names of that application. For Example:  apache application has 8 tags. Then expected response would be apache   1.2, 1.4, 1.8, 2.0 release, baseline, build , prod.

Comment: Try playing with this ``oc get is python -n openshift --template='{{.metadata.name}}{{range .spec.tags}}{{" "}}{{.name}}{{end}}{{"\n"}}'``. This will output ``python 2.7 3.3 3.4 3.5 3.6 latest``.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton super helpful! thank you! question - if I wanted to add the image created date / age at the end do you know the construct? I tried `{{.created}}` with no luck :(

Comment: You may want to look at ``imagestreamtag`` objects instead if need more detail that not in the ``imagestream`` object. Use ``oc get imagestreamtag imagename:tagname -o json`` and see if details are in there.

Answer (score 3):

You may get details from imagestreamtag object. If you need formatted tags only as a list you can execute this command.

```
oc get imagestreams imagename -o jsonpath='{range .status.tags[*]}{.tag}{"\n"}'
```

This will return something like this as result as formatted:

```
20.10.321
20.13.328
20.14.333
20.14.338
20.16.342
```

Comment: This is pretty nice for displaying the tags for a specific `imagename`, but is there a way to do this for all the images in the namespace?  That is, all the images in a project?  

I tried the command omitting the `imagename`, but there was no output.  I know there are tags for the images in my project (at least `latest`) because I see them if I use the command `oc get imagestreams`.